# Does cmake ignore .hpp file changes?

Tags: c++, templates, build, dependencies, cmake

I have this C++ project I'm building with cmake. It seems like changes I make to .hpp files don't result in a rebuild of the .o file of the .cpp including the .hpp . Is that really the case or am I getting something wrong?

Also, how can I tell cmake to notice `#include "something.hpp" dependencies?

Comment: Did you include the headers as part of the project? It may be the case that CMake is considering them as "external" entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMake should automatically track such dependencies when `include_directories()` is used to specify the directory where headers should be found. If instead you set up `-I` flags in the compiler flags, CMake do not track dependencies.

Comment: But what about if it's an included .hpp in the current directory?

Comment: @einpoklum I think CMake parses your files and detect automatically the dependency.

Comment: Apparently it doesn't :-(

Comment: @einpoklum Please create a new question. I can assure you that it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the header files alongside your source files to a target. This will make e.g. the Makefile automatically generate header dependency information and recompile source files including a header file that was modified since the last build.